# How to get get a reference to a component used in JSX to call method on it?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

The example code is for ionic-react, but my actual problem is independent of ionic, it is a React/JSX related question.

The simplified render method:

```
return (
  <IonPage>
    <IonContent>
      <div>Hello!</div>
    </IonContent>
  </IonPage>
)
```

I need to get a reference to IonContent Component. I do NOT need a refernce to the HTMLElement (for which I could use React.createRef()). Is it possible and how could I get it?

Background info:
IonContent defines a getScrollElement() method (see: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#methods). I need to access this to programmatically scroll the content. Setting scrollTop on the ion-content HTMLElement didn't work for me and as I understand the docs it isn't supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the actual reference, but it returns a promise so you might want to resolve it: `getScrollElement() => Promise<HTMLElement>`

```
<IonContent ref={myRef}>
  <div>Hello!</div>
</IonContent>;

// getScrollElement returns a promise in async func
const scrollElement = await myRef.current.getScrollElement();
```

Answer (score 3):

for anyone who is looking for TypeScript answer.

```
const contentEle = useRef<HTMLIonContentElement>(null);
const scrollEle = await contentEle.current?.getScrollElement();
scrollEle?.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
    
return (
   <IonContent ref={contentEle}>
       ...
   </IonContent>
)
```